# Issue with parsed text with HTMLCleaner - spaces at the begining of text

Tags: android, htmlcleaner

I'm able to get text using HTMLCleaner from website. The problem is that when I set the text to  a TextView it shows the beginning of the text with a big space on it. [image: screenshot]

I have tried `android:gravity` but nothing happened.

Please help.

Here is my Code:

```
    private class SiteParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        String output = null;

        try {
            HtmlHelper hh = new HtmlHelper(new URL(arg[0]));
            List<TagNode> news = hh.getnewsByClass("TextoPrint");

            for (Iterator<TagNode> iterator = newss.iterator(); iterator
                    .hasNext();) {
                TagNode divElement = (TagNode) iterator.next();
                output = divElement.getText().toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String output) {


        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("body",output);
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(act, MyView.class);
        mainIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
        act.finish();



    }
}

public class HtmlHelper {
    TagNode rootNode;

    public HtmlHelper(URL htmlPage) throws IOException, XPatherException {
        HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
        rootNode = cleaner.clean(htmlPage);

    }

    List<TagNode> getnewsByClass(String Classname){
        List<TagNode> newsList = new ArrayList<TagNode>();


        TagNode divElements[] = rootNode.getElementsByName("div", true);
        for (int i = 0; divElements != null && i < divElements.length; i++) {
            String classType =  divElements[i].getAttributeByName("id");
            if (classType != null && classType.equals(Classname)) {
                newsList.add(divElements[i]);
            }
        }

        return newsList;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help to see the layout XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing any leading (and trailing) whitespace with `trim()`:

```
output = divElement.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: Thanks works great! Now one last thing, the text is not formatted not reading the <br> tags.

Comment: When you use `setText()` tell the TextView to use the HTML tags with `setText(Html.fromHtml(output));`. Understand that TextViews support a limited amount of HTML tags.

Comment: If you only want to work with `<br/>` tags, you can use `String#replace("<br>", "\n")` or maybe "\r\n".